# Custom styling on Facebook's LikeBox plugin - is it possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to ask - is it possible to apply my custom CSS into the LikeBox code? I would like it to appear just as on www.autentika.pl. Does it matter whether it is an IFrame, XFBML, or simply HTML? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this site: [multipla.tv](http://multipla.tv)
This is done here also.
You should add the old version of fan the box:

```
<fb:fan profile_id="106908749418612" stream="" connections="14" width="696" height="113" css="http://multipla.tv/css/facebook.css?3159"></fb:fan>
```

to you website and include js file:

```
http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/pl_PL
```

Just before ending html tag insert code given by facebook after generating fb likebox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27010550-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Remember to change the setAccount for yours.
And one more think.
In head you should insert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init("j4eb6a5dd7554377955544101");</script>
```

The argument of init is your id. You can find it when you search the javascript included in the iframe of a normal fb likebox.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook intentionally makes this difficult. You can sort of do it via click jacking but if you get caught Facebook will disable your likes as it is very much against their TOS.